# Create a background using some logic (not just an animated background)?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-background

I'm planning to make a Android Widget with some countdown based on current date, but would be perfect if I could do that as a Background instead.
I googled a little and didn't found any information on this matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is an excellent tutorial on CodeProject that demonstrates exactly how to do this.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108390/How-To-Create-Android-Live-Wallpaper)